# Why does the excel TEXT(value,format_text) function's format_text argument not take "short date" as a valid value?

Tags: excel, date, text, format, cell

The VBA [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755%28v=office.15%29.aspx)(expression,[format])  function's format argument is able to handle "short date". Is there a workaround to use "short date" with the TEXT function? I don't want to use VBA.

I tried using the excel [CELL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/cell-function-HP010062392.aspx)("format",reference) function to get the system short date format to use with the TEXT function but it is useless as it returns mm/dd/yyyy even if I use m/d/yyyy in my windows regional settings.

So basically my question is this - Is there a workaround to use "short date" with the TEXT function?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the problem...............if I put:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"m/dd/yyyy")
```

in a cell, it displays:

**4/18/2014**

This is on a Win 7 - Excel 2007 machine.

Comment: yes but if I share the report with someone in the UK, he/she will be confused with dates such as "4/12/2014". I want the TEXT function to display the date value as text in the SYSTEM Date Format and not some predetermined format.